# Why my UIWebview cannot 'full' screen?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebview` built on XIB with following settings:

```
[self.webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
self.webView.opaque = NO;
```

However, there are some white spaces on bottom, while if I try on my Mac's Chrome and iOS Simulator's Safari, it doesn't have that white space. What setting that I lack in my `UIWebview`?

Comment: did you use autolayout?

Comment: no. i have figured out that actually the uiwebview is not in full height lol

Comment: anyways i have posted a solution,. May be it might be useful for you though. so take a glance at my solution. I have set the frames programmatically over there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)initWebView {
    self.webView.scalesPageToFit=NO;
    [self.webView setOpaque:NO];
    self.webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin ;
    [(UIScrollView*)[self.webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [(UIScrollView*)[self.webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [self.webView.scrollView flashScrollIndicators];
    self.webView.frame=self.view.bounds;
    self.webView.opaque = NO;
    self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

in your viewDidLoad method invoke it later as,

```
[self initWebView ];
```